# Equivalent of Rs plot command for a data frame in python

Tags: python, r

In R with a single command, you can get a graph that allows you to visualise every pairing of columns on a dataset

for example
plot(iris_df)

gives this image, where iris_df is a dataframe containing the famous [iris dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set). Is there a similar command in a python package that lets you view a dataset easily?

[image: plot(iris)]

Comment: How about the `seaborn.pairplot`? Documentation [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html)